# I am trying to add custom validation for variables in my terraform script using map but i am facing error

Tags: variables, amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to add custom validation for the variables in my terraform script for S3 bucket. But i am facing an error that is mentioned as below:

```
Reference to undeclared input variable

  on main.tf line 2, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "gouth_bucket_1_apr_2021":
   2:   bucket = var.bucket #"terraform-s3-bucket"

An input variable with the name "bucket" has not been declared. This variable
can be declared with a variable "bucket" {} block."
```

Can anyone help me on the same.please let me know which file needs the necessary changes and how.

Thanks in Advance

Below is my code :

```
main.tf :

    resource "aws_s3_bucket" "gouth_bucket_1_apr_2021" {
      bucket = var.bucket 
      acl = "private"
      tags= var.tags
    }
```

```
s3.tfvars :

    bucket = "first-bucket-gouth"
    
    #Variables of Tags
    tags= {
    name = "s3bucket",
    account_id = "1234567",
    owner = "abc@def.com",
    os= "windows",
    backup = "N",
    application = "abc",
    description = "s3 bucket",
    env = "dev",
    ticketid = "101",
    marketami = "NA",
    patching = "NA",
    dc = "bangalore"
    }
```

```
validation.tf :

    variable "tags" {
        type = map(string)
        
        validation {
            condition = length(var.tags["env"]) > 0
            error_message = "Environment tag is required !!"
        }
        validation {
            condition = length(var.tags["owner"]) > 0
            error_message = "Owner tag is required !!"
        }
        validation {
            condition = length(var.tags["dc"]) > 0
            error_message = "DC tag is required !!"
        }
        validation {
            condition = can(var.tags["account_id"])
            error_message = "Acoount ID tag is required!!"
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Please make sure your question is fully representative of your actual error and code.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two potential issues.

1. You are referencing `var.bucket` in your resource, but you are not defining a variable for it anywhere in your definition. This could simply look like:

```
variable "bucket" {}
```

2. You may not be picking up your tfvars file, if you are running Terraform with the tfvars file as an option like so `terraform plan -var-file=s3.tfvars` then thats ok, or you can rename your tfvars file to `something.auto.tfvars` or `terraform.tfvars` to get automatically used. (See > https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files)

I hope this answers your question.